# .net microphone record save to file in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna

i need to know how to save a sound stream in a file on the fly after record

this is my code, that i need to save an external file wav or smth.

so at that point here there are record button play button and play objects

```
  private void recordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get audio data in 1/2 second chunks
        microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

        // Allocate memory to hold the audio data
        buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];

        // Set the stream back to zero in case there is already something in it
        stream.SetLength(0);

        // Start recording
        microphone.Start();

        SetButtonStates(false, false, true);
        UserHelp.Text = "recording";
        // StatusImage.Source = microphoneImage;
    }

      private void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (stream.Length > 0)
        {
            // Update the UI to reflect that
            // sound is playing
            SetButtonStates(false, false, true);
            UserHelp.Text = "play";

            // Play the audio in a new thread so the UI can update.
            Thread soundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(playSound));
            soundThread.Start();
        }
    }
    private void playSound()
    {
        // Play audio using SoundEffectInstance so we can monitor it's State 
        // and update the UI in the dt_Tick handler when it is done playing.
        SoundEffect sound = new SoundEffect(stream.ToArray(), microphone.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
        soundInstance = sound.CreateInstance();
        soundIsPlaying = true;
        soundInstance.Play();
    }
```

Comment: See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the .wav header properly and then write the audio stream.
Check [this example](http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/record-and-store-audio-in-isolated-storage-in-windows-phone-8/)